# Detecting program messagebox

Tags: c#

I have a C++ game that will *sometimes* show a `MessageBox` error when launching it on Windows 10 and will not launch properly. 80% of the time it will launch properly and I can use it.

I want to avoid trying to launch it multiple times manually, so I was thinking about making an application that does it for me.

But that I mean - try and launch the game. Wait for the `MessageBox` detection. If it does detect the `MessageBox`, kill the game and retry. If 5 seconds passed and there's no `MessageBox`, exit the application.

I know I can use `FindWindow`, and then `GetDlgItem` and use `GetWindowText` to check if that's a `MessagBox`, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    internal static extern int GetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd, StringBuilder text, int count);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr GetDlgItem(IntPtr hDlg, int nIDDlgItem);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IntPtr gameHandle = FindWindow(null, "Game");

        while (gameHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            gameHandle = FindWindow(null, "Game");
        }

        IntPtr dlgHandle = GetDlgItem(gameHandle, 0xFFFF);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        GetWindowText(dlgHandle, sb, 30);
        Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
    }
```

For some reason, `dlgHandle` returns 0.

After I've solved that, I can check if the `MessageBox` text matches the error and then I can know if it's an error or not. Why does it return 0 though?

**EDIT:** I fear that the game is using it's own `MessageBox` implementation, and that's why `GetDlgItem` is returning 0. Here's a picture of the `MessageBox` it sends: [image]

Comment: Have you poked at it with Spy++? [EnumChildWindows](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.enumchildwindows) is another avenue. If it's WPF or something weird, you may be in trouble, but cross that bridge when you get there.

Comment: @EdPlunkett That's a great suggestion. Used Spy++ and it said the class is `#32770 (Dialog)`. I tried to use `FindWindowsEx` on that class but it still returns 0.

Comment: For the text block itself? On a regular Win32 MessageBox, I get that for the dialog (it's the standard windowclass for Win32 CreateDialog dialogs), but if I drag the crosshairs thing over the text itself (it gets a heavy black outline while I'm over it), I see the class as "Static". I unclick, click OK in that crosshairs dialog, and I see the Property Inspector dialog for the Static control: Control ID `0000FFFF` , etc. etc. Win32 calls a label a "Static" control, as in "static text"

Comment: @EdPlunkett It does for both the block and for both text. It only differs when I'm pointing it on the OK button, of course. But it says `#32770 (Dialog)` on both text and window.

Comment: @EdPlunkett What if I check the class of the process? If it's not `#32770 (Dialog)`, then I know the process launched correctly. What do you think?

Comment: That's probably good enough. I guess it'd better be! I just checked the WPF and winforms MessageBox.Show() methods btw, and both are giving me the same standard Win32 message box dialog with the Static control. So that game you have is doing something there.

Comment: @EdPlunkett How can I check for the class though? Is there an external method for it?

Comment: [Win32 GetClassName(HWND, LPTSTR, int)](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.getclassname) should do it